# How do I search for emails with a subject prefix using python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have an inbox which receives mails every 15 mins.
The subject of each is different - it has a fixed prefix and then concatinated with date and time.
for example:
subject : [External] PNR Assignment File-JAPA-1_4/18/2023 8:34:37 AM

The ***[External] PNR Assignment File-JAPA*** part is constant.
I want to restrict the mails based on subject.

```
subject=return_mail_subject(region_selected)
path=return_path(region_selected)
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") #Opens Microsoft Outlook
folder = outlook.Folders.Item(inbox)
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
messages = inbox.Items  #Get emails
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F""like 'subject'")
```

Wrote this code where subject variable = [External] PNR Assignment File-JAPA
But this gives an error.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are right to use `0x0E1D001F` (`PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT`), but you need to use the standard "%" SQL wildcard:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F""like '[External] PNR Assignment File-JAPA%'")
```